# sqlite insert with primary key

Tags: ios, sqlite

I use sqlite(3.7.4) in iphone.
I create a table like:

```
create table A (UserName varchar (50) primary key, Num integer);
```

Then I insert the record below twice:

```
('abc',1);
```

Normally there should be only one record in DB.
However I found in the DB

```
(abc,1);
(  ,1);
```

I'm confused that as UserName is `primary key` and why there are two records!
I don't know what's the problem.
Can anyone help me?

thank you.

Comment: Just find it's my colleague's mistake.In the case above, there will never be the two records like that. But Thank you all the same,Vik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you want use username as primary key. Primary key should unique identify record. What is why when you inserted twice in second time you have primary key constraint violation

```
create table A (UserName varchar (50) primary key, Num integer, unique (UserName));
```

Comment: it depends on our business logic.The circumstance is that sometimes we don't know whether the record exists in the DB.

Comment: @scorpiozj you can tyr to use unique keyword to specify unique column